# IndexError from random character in string

Tags: python, string, random

Python 2.7.6 on OS X or Python 2.6.6 on CentOS

Given a string: 'abcdefghijklmno'
Choose a random character from that string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
symbols = 'abcdefghijklmnop'
print symbols[random.randint(1, len(symbols))]
```

The result is usually what I expect, a random character from that string. However running this multiple times:

```
$ for i in {1..100}; do python test.py; done;
```

Occasionally returns an IndexError:

```
....    
h
f
f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print symbols[random.randint(1, len(symbols))]
IndexError: string index out of range
b
n
....
```

I first considered perhaps the random number generator had a bug in OS X, so I tried it on CentOS as well, but got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List indices start from zero, not one. Thus the `randint()` call should read

```
randint(0, len(symbols) - 1)
```

It would arguably be clearer to use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) instead of dealing with indices directly:

```
print random.choice(symbols)
```

Comment: and `random.randrange()` would give you `range()` semantics instead.

Comment: I actually hadn't realized that 0 counted as a number.